# Magento shopping cart rule issue

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

When i apply shopping cart rule on cart in which cart item have less amount then coupon amount then grant total amount goes into negative value.

I have try to debug the issue but not succeed. Can you guys help me out how can i resolve the issue.

Mangeto 1.6.2

Comment: can you share the configuration of the cart rule so we can help

Comment: I figure out the issue. Things are working fine when i change the tax calculation before tax..

Comment: cool, glad you solved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some tax calculation issue in the magneto 1.6. So its calculating the wrong amount during checkout. Things are working fine after changes GST calculation "Apply Customer Tax" - Before Discount as shown in http://screencast.com/t/UHtJtYZiLa